# Can ALL untagged docker.io images be safely removed?

Tags: image, docker

I can't find anywhere a question on this answer.
When working with docker.io there are a lot of untagged images created.
My question is: If I remove them, do I risk to break anything?
I mean is it possible that another tagged (!) image relies on them, and stops functioning when I remove the untagged child?

Is this true in ALL cases?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not just try? ;)

Here's a small list of untagged images on my test system:

```
# docker images -a
REPOSITORY   TAG    IMAGE ID            CREATED             VIRTUAL SIZE
[...]
<none>              3fe716bafb0d        36 hours ago        381.2 MB
<none>              07bce059bd37        36 hours ago        380.3 MB
<none>              e1fef18f0eda        36 hours ago        380.3 MB
<none>              **a7e21150f14d**        36 hours ago        380.3 MB
```

Let's remove an image on which another image depends:

```
# docker rmi a7e21150f14d
Error: Conflict, a7e21150f14d wasn't deleted
2014/06/19 18:21:45 Error: failed to remove one or more images
```

Ok, try with the `force` option now:

```
# docker rmi -f a7e21150f14d
Error: Conflict, a7e21150f14d wasn't deleted
2014/06/19 18:24:11 Error: failed to remove one or more images
```

```
# docker images -a | grep a7e21150f14d                                   
<none>              a7e21150f14d        36 hours ago        380.3 MB
```

Still there.

Note : running the same test, this time on a **tagged** image will untag it, but there's no way to remove it as long as something depends on it.

But now, if I remove the **topmost** image, it will automatically clean/remove its unused dependencies:

`# docker rmi 3fe716bafb0d <-- this is my top image
    Deleted: 3fe716bafb0da75ef9c8691cdcf4e998622963489577c8b34ca2d76ccca20efd
    Deleted: 07bce059bd37aedef85218f6112f0ed492971afaa8ba0d567ae8ca77f1676ff6
    Deleted: e1fef18f0eda0cb60149c5a739f7f4944dbfbfbc1b7d2a07402f5ca52731a7c9
    Deleted: a7e21150f14d 20bce85bec30ef6658091a8ce1e85bee64437bf76f9567780c0e`

Comment: thanks mbarthelemy!! I have a lot of untagged images in my production system and was always afraid of deleting them. I know now that I can delete them without harm ;)